A jumping grid!
Replace the question marks with the correct numbers and explain the reason why.

  6 9 0 2 0 0
  9 1 2 9 9 1
  8 0 0 2 2 1
  0 2 4 0 0 2
  0 ? ? ? ? 2
  0 2 6 1 0 2

  ╎ ╎ ╎ ╎ ╎ ╎
 
  ╎ ╎ ╎ ╎ ╎ ╎
  
  ╎ ╎ ╎ ╎ ╎ ╎
   
  -- -- -- 
  -- -- --
  -- -- --
  -- -- --
  -- -- --
  -- -- --

Hint 1

 Why are they grouped pairwise? First vertical, then horizontal. What can that possibly hint towards?

Hint 2

 Change

Hint 3

 I don't mean change the numbers themselves, I mean change p.......


The answer is:

 $\overline{ABCD} = 2024$.

Here is the reason:

 $$\left[\begin{matrix} 6 &9 &0 &2 &0 &0\\ 9 &1& 2 &9 &9 &1\\ 8& 0& 0 &2 &2& 1\\ 0& 2 &4 &0 &0 &2\\  0 &A& B &C &D &2\\  0& 2 &6 &1 &0 &2\\ \end{matrix}\right]$$ is the original matrix; swap every pair of rows to get $$\left[\begin{matrix}  9 &1 &2 &9 &9 &1\\  6 &9 &0 &2 &0 &0\\  0 &2 &4 &0 &0 &2\\  8 &0 &0 &2 &2 &1\\   0 &2 &6 &1 &0 &2\\  0 &A &B &C &D &2\\  \end{matrix}\right]$$ then swap every pair of columns to get $$\left[\begin{matrix}  1 &9 &9 &2 &1 &9\\  9 &6 &2 &0 &0 &0\\  2 &0 &0 &4 &2 &0\\  0 &8 &2 &0 &1 &2\\   2 &0 &1 &6 &2 &0\\  A &0 &C &B &2 &D\\  \end{matrix}\right]$$
 and the numbers in reading order form the sequence: 1992, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016, 20A0, CB2D, which are the most recent leap ("jumping") years, so A=2, B=0, C=2, D=4


Nice job, correct! If you could just perhaps explain the title, related to these numbers, that would be great.

"Whzcvat" ersreerq gb yrnc lrnef. Naq gur nafjre vf bsp gur pheerag yrnc lrne.
